# Peter Norvig's Game of Life

Tags: python, optimization, conways-game-of-life

i was looking at this code 
[Peter Norvig's Game of Life implementation](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/Life.ipynb)
when i noticed this:

```
def next_generation(world):
"The set of live cells in the next generation."
possible_cells = counts = neighbor_counts(world)
return {cell for cell in possible_cells
        if (counts[cell] == 3) 
        or (counts[cell] == 2 and cell in world)}
```

What is the reason to use `counts` instead of `possible_cells`?

Comment: Maybe that's to make the code shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Norvig explains [in the comments](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/Life.ipynb) (immediately above the code in the IPython cell `In [1]`):

> Note that in `next_generation` the `neighbor_counts` is used two ways so I decided to use two different names for clarity: `possible_cells` is used to iterate over all cells that might be live, and `counts` is used to check if a cell has the right number of neighbors.

Comment: Stupid me... I read this sentence 3 times before, but only inside a yellow box i was able to understand